# bootstrap select2: ability to select group

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'd like to replace [MultiSelect](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) with [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), but the first has a wonderful feature which allows you to click on the group title to match all its subitems.

Is it possible to do something like that with select2?

Comment: I have used the select2 but not MultiSelect. Though I have just checked the Multiselect group demo from the url http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/. I do not think select2 provides a support like that.

Comment: I believe the same, that's why I asked

Answer (score 0):

select2 does allow you to select the optgroup itself if it has an id attribute.

if you want to select subitems you can listen to change event, see if an optgroup was selected, and replace the selection with all children. its a bit more work but can be done.

Comment: I just filed a [bug](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/1965) ;) I thought it would be nice to have it in the main code. I tried doing myself but I'm not so familiar with js OOP. I will check out later if I can better understand

Comment: why is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qUh5V/) not working? I added the "id" to optgroup but doesn't seem to be clickable